# superimpose different images to generate a single image in android

Tags: android

In my app I need to process multiple images and output into
one final image.

For example, in a stack of 3 images (like photoshop layers) the images will need to be processed and
rendered to a final image.

```
image 1, multiply, 50%
image 2, saturation, 50%
image 3, color, 50%
```

There are multiple libraries for image processing. But I am not sure how to generate a single image using multiple overlapping images. Does Android have any feature to support this. I tried searching for it but did not find anything. Kindly advise.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the bitmap of a view by calling getDrawingCache() on the view. So in your case, you can have a Relativelayout with your 3 images. Then just have a method to return the bitmap of the layout. Ex:

```
private Bitmap getViewBitmap(View v) {
        v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        return v.getDrawingCache();
}
```

Just pass your layout or any other view and you will get the bitmap of it

[Android View Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getDrawingCache%28boolean%29)